# Why does my 2006 jeep commander have no heat?

Tags: heater

I have a 2006 jeep commander. new heater core, new thermostat, and door actuator but no heat. could someone please help me get some heat

Comment: You should have the DTC's pulled from the hvac system and bcm. May give you a good starting point.

Comment: "No heat" isn't precise enough. Does the engine heat up? Does the heater fan move air through into the cabin?